Largest smallest integer solution
I have the following system of equations, for $i$ in $1,\ldots,n$:
$$
\mathbf{a_i} \cdot \mathbf{x} = y
$$
The variables are $\mathbf{x}$ - a vector of $n$ non-negative integers, and $y$ - a positive integer. The $\mathbf{a_i}$ are vectors of size $n$ with binary elements (0 or 1).
For any solution $(x,y)$ and any positive integer $k$, $(kx, ky)$ is a solution too; but for any system that has at least one solution, there is a minimal solution - a solution with the smallest value of $y$.
What is an upper bound on the value of $y$ in the minimal solution, as a function of $n$?
EXAMPLE: Suppose $n=3$, $a_1=[0,1,1]$, $a_2=[1,0,1]$ and $a_3=[1,1,0]$. Then the minimal solution is $x=(1,1,1)$ and $y=2$. In general, for any $n\geq 3$, if each $a_i$ is a vector with $n-1$ ones and $1$ zero, then the minimal solution is $x=(1,\ldots,1)$ and $y=n-1$.
Are there cases in which the value of $y$ is substantially larger than $n$? What is the largest possible value of $y$ (over all sets of binary vectors $a_i$) as a function of $n$?

Clearly $y=0$ and $a_i=0$ are meant to be excluded ... but then (if I understand the setup) sometimes there are no solutions—consider $a_1=(1,0)$, $a_2=(0,1)$, $a_3=(1,1)$.

I guess the bound will happen when the $a_i$ forms a $0$-$1$ matrix of maximal determinant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39786/maximum-determinant-of-0-1-valued-n-times-n-matrices, so you will get an $n^n$-ish bound (in case there exists a solution).

@GregMartin Indeed, $y$ should be a positive integer. Your example does not fit the question, as the size of the $a_i$ vectors should be $n$, but in general there can be cases without a solution; I am only interested in cases in which a solution exists.

@caduk I also guessed it is somehow related to the $n^{n/2}$ bound, but was not sure how to formally prove the relation.

In fact, we are not interested in the magnitude of the determinant, but in the magnitude of the inverse's coefficients. This answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/182393/381833 give something akin to $\sqrt{n}^n$

@caduk this makes sense, but the matrix in my case is not square (there are $n$ equations in $n+1$ variables). How exactly do you use the inverse matrix coefficients to get a solution?

This answer is under reconstruction. It refers to the old version of my linked answer, but with the new version I hope to improve the bound to $n^{n/2}$.

Luckily, similarly to this  answer to your question (with the set $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ instead of $V$) we can show that in a minimal solution $y$ is at most $(n+1)^n$.

Thanks! Is there also a matching lower bound - an example where $y$ is exponential in $n$?

@ErelSegal-Halevi I tried to construct the respective matrices using available knowledge, but failed.
So, currently the last hope is to check all possible $n\times n$ binary matrices with the rows $\mathbf{a_i}$ for small $n$ (say, for $n\le 6$ or $n\le 7$), find among them those which provide the biggest value for $y$ in the minimal solution, then try to find patterns in these matrices and  generalize it to bigger $n$. I am going to discuss a respective program with my colleague.
